# Executing an external rails project command from Java application

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm working on a big system that interconnects different platforms in different languages. Two of these platforms are a RoR website and a Java application whose task is to insert data (no matter where from) to the RoR PostgreSQL database. Currently, I was using simple SQL queries to insert, for example, a product. This is working right, however, I can't take advantage of framework's included tools like timestamps and model callbacks.

The question is, is there a way to, instead of executing those SQL queries, execute rails console commands, considering my Java application runs completely apart the RoR application? If you need to know, I'm using rails 4.

Please excuse my english and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is a good idea at all. But you can achieve this if the java application connects to the same machine RoR is running. You can then use rails runner or you can execute some rake task. The use of rails runner is really simple, check out this example from the official documentation from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner

```
$ bin/rails runner -e staging "Model.long_running_method"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did as @IvanT suggested, however despite the diverse approaches I can't make it work, here's one of the codes I tried:

```
String railsCmd = "Product.where(:category_id => 9).each { |p| p.update_attribute(:brand, 'NO BRAND') }";
String wholeCommand = "rails runner -e development \"" + railsCmd + "\"";

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(wholeCommand, null, new File("/path/to/rails/project/bin"));
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;            
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    output.append(line).append("\n");
}
System.out.println(output.toString());
```

It takes a couple seconds to process, as it's doing something, but there is no change in products themselves. I tried the command directly in the terminal and works good.

I would also like to know why you think it's not a good idea.

Thank you for your time.